# Issue with sending test email - Sitecore Email Campaign Manager 3.3

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

When I try to send test email(all templates except Plain Text) I see this error in the log:

```
ERROR Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The connection to the remote server can not be established.
Source: System
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.WebContent.DownloadString (String url, Boolean useIisCredentials, String user agent)
nested exception
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: It could not be established because the target machine actively refused
```

When I test it with Plain Text message all works fine.

On the ecm.requestbody page I see this exception:

```
exception: The connection to the remote server can not be established.
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()
    at ASP.sitecore_admin_ecm_requestbody_aspx.DownloadString (String url, Boolean useIisCredentials, String iisUser, String iisPass)
```

Fields IIS.User and IIS.Password in the file Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config is also filled

Comment: Is anonymous access disabled in IIS? If not, you should not fill out IIS.User and IIS.Password. See the documentation here https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/configuration/the_exm_configuration_settings.

Comment: anonymous access is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid issue with wrong hostname in my hosts(system32/driver/etc/hosts) file

Answer (score 0):

Check your Base URL setting on your EXM manager root - it should be the URL of your Sitecore instance.

More on manager roots here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/30/setting_up_exm/the_manager_root/the_manager_root_settings

If that doesn't fix your issue there's a good knowledge base article here:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/553662

Comment: Base URL is filled correctly. I edited my question with info from ecm.requestbody page

Comment: Ok, I've had an issue in the past with this and it was a process of elimination. You can maybe try using Fiddler to examine the request to try and work out exactly whats going on. It's likely that there is something interfering with the request. For example the issue I had was due to a New relic agent interfering with the request.

Comment: Someone has posted his solution at http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2018/11/sitecore-error-troubleshooting.html